# Prove $\int s d \mu = \sum^n_{j=1} a_j \mu(A_j)$ for $s=\sum^n_{j=1} a_j 1_{A_j}$ not a standard representation of $s$.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal E, \mu)$ be a measure space. Let $s \in \mathcal S\mathcal M(\mathcal E)^+$ be a simple function written as $s= \sum^n_{j=1} a_j 1_{A_j}$ , $a_j \ge 0, A_j \in \mathcal E$.

Prove $\int s d \mu = \sum^n_{j=1} a_j \mu(A_j)$ for $s=\sum^n_{j=1} a_j 1_{A_j}$ not a standard representation of $s$.

I have shown that $\int s d \mu = \sup \{I_{\mu} : s \in \mathcal S\mathcal M(\mathcal E)^+ \land s \le f \} = I_u(s)$ (sum of a standard representation of $s$).

How can I show that this equality holds for $s= \sum^n_{j=1} a_j 1_{A_j}$ not a standard representation of $s$?

> Defintion:
>   A standard representation of $s \in \mathcal S \mathcal M(\mathcal E)^+$ is $s=\sum_{j=1}^n a_j 1_{A_j}$ such that $a_j \ge 0$, the $A_j$'s are disjoint and $\bigcup A_j = \mathcal E$.

A nonstandard representation is just any other representation of $s$ written as $s=\sum_{j=1}^n a_j 1_{A_j}$ where the $A_j \in \mathcal E$ are not neccesarily disjoint, $a_j \ge 0$ and it is not neccesarily true that $\bigcup A_j = \mathcal E$.

Comment: "I want to prove $\int sd\mu=\sum_k a_j 1_{A_j}$" - Doesn't make sense. The LHS is a real number, the RHS is a function.

Comment: You are right. I've corrected it. I know that every two standard representations of $s$ result in the same value of $I_{\mu}(s)$ the $\mu$-integral of $s$. And $\int s d \mu = I_{\mu}(s)$ (otherwise we have two different $\mu$-integrals of the same function from $\bar {\mathcal M}(\mathcal E)^+$. However, if $s$ is written as a simple function in a nonstandard way the equality holds too ?

Comment: What does non-standard mean? In any case, if you have established linearity of the integral, then it should be straightforward to show.

Comment: I've updated the question with a definition and an explanation of "nonstandard".

Answer (score 1):

Hint: One wants to show that two finite linear combinations $L_1$ and $L_2$ of indicator functions representing $s$ yield integrals $I_1$ and $I_2$ which coincide.

One can write $s$ as a *third* finite linear combination $L$ of indicator functions *finer* than $L_1$ and $L_2$ and consider the integral $I$ of $s$ that $L$ yields. Decomposing each subset appearing in $L_1$ as a disjoint union of subsets appearing in $L$, one sees that $I_1$ and $I$ coincide. Likewise for $I_2$ and $I$. QED.

Comment: Thank you @Did. What exactly do you mean by "finer" ?

Comment: Subdivision L is finer than subdivision K if every subset appearing in K is the union of some subsets appearing in L.

Comment: I've been trying for a couple of hours to apply what you have written for the exercise, however, I've not yet come to a solution. I get sums that not neccesarily sum to the same thing.
Would you show your approach on a small example of yours ? It would help me alot.

Comment: One can always refine any representation into a standard one, then the question is to compare the "integrals" associated to two standard representations. Which of these two steps is a problem?